# Python pandas - grouping by and summarizing on a field

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been playing with Panda's DataFrames recently, and struggling to analyze some multi-dimensional data.

Let's say I have some data such as below:

```
order | sample | feature1 | feature2
-------------------------------------
1234  | A      | 0.20     | 0.45
1234  | B      | 0.71     | 0.08
1234  | C      | 0.21     | 0.02
1234  | D      | 0.87     | 0.88
5678  | A      | 0.76     | 0.42
5678  | B      | 0.01     | 0.03
5678  | C      | 0.29     | 0.91
5678  | D      | 0.70     | 0.78
```

And I want to have in output everything grouped by order and where each feature is summarized by sample:

```
order | feature1                  | feature2 
      | A    | B    | C    | D    | A    | B    | C    | D   
------------------------------------------------------------
1234  | 0.20 | 0.71 | 0.21 | 0.87 | 0.45 | 0.08 | 0.02 | 0.88
5678  | 0.76 | 0.01 | 0.29 | 0.70 | 0.42 | 0.03 | 0.91 | 0.78
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
from pandas import *
df = DataFrame({"order": [1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 5678, 5678, 5678, 5678], "sample": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"], "feature1": [0.20, 0.71, 0.21, 0.87, 0.76, 0.01, 0.29, 0.70], "feature2": [0.45, 0.08, 0.02, 0.88, 0.42, 0.03, 0.91, 0.78]})
byorder = df.groupby("order")
# not sure how to go from 1 groupby object to a new dataframe having what i need
```

Do you have any thoughts on how I can end up with a new DataFrame containing the data aggregated like I need? Maybe DataFrames are not the right tool for doing this kind of manipulation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**`pivot`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-pivoting-dataframe-objects)

```
>>> df.pivot(index='order', columns='sample')
       feature1                   feature2
sample        A     B     C     D        A     B     C     D
order
1234       0.20  0.71  0.21  0.87     0.45  0.08  0.02  0.88
5678       0.76  0.01  0.29  0.70     0.42  0.03  0.91  0.78
```

Comment: This is actually pretty cool, didn't know there was such an elegant way to do this, thanks !

Comment: @CharlesMenguy: Just learnt this about myself :-) Glad to help out!